# Fetching data in background in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am new to ReactNative. I need to fetch some data using API and need to know if react-native does fetch operation in background thread or in main thread. If not then how can it be achieved?

Comment: why does it have to be in the background, all fetch calls are done async. what are you trying to achieve

Comment: In Native apps, we always do long running operations in background for example in android, either in separate thread or service component. Is there any similar mechanism available in react-native